# How to detect colored pixel of Sprite3D texture with perspective camera ray?

Tags: sprites, godot, raycasting

I've tried to ray cast my mouse position to Sprite3D on screen but I have some problems with it.

```
func _input(event):
    if event is InputEventMouse:
        mouse = event.position
    if event is InputEventMouseButton and event.pressed:
        if event.button_index == MOUSE_BUTTON_LEFT:
            get_selection()

func get_selection():
    var worldspace = player.camera_3d.get_world_3d().direct_space_state
    var start = player.camera_3d.project_ray_origin(mouse)
    var end = player.camera_3d.project_position(mouse, 1000)
    
    var query = PhysicsRayQueryParameters3D.create(start, end)

    var result = worldspace.intersect_ray(query)
```

**Brief setting of my project**
My character/enemy is a Sprite3D in CharacterBody3D with small collision box only on its feet. I want the mouse to detect the shape of colored pixels of my character/enemy I saw on screen but intersect_ray() always return with collider in the object, so it went through the character to the floor object instead.

**Why I don't set the collision box to match the height of sprite?**
Camera is attached to player with 45 degree angle looking down to the player and it can zoom-in-out and tilt then it will look_at() player again  at its new position. While tilting, character's visual is also tilted to parallel with camera. So I think its collision box couldn't be the same size as sprite because sprite's height will be changing all the time and collision box cannot be tilted into the ground too.

```
visuals.rotation.x = camera_3d.rotation.x
```

**So my question is...**
Is there a way to do a manual raycasting? or to calculate colored pixels' positions from characters/enemy on screen compare to mouse position and know if it's player or enemy. Please keep in mind that camera can zoom-in or zoom-out and tilting.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading the pixels would involve getting the texture from the viewport and querying that. Which is doable, if somewhat annoying. It is similar to: [How would I mask the player node out of a canvas shader?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/207347/10408).

---

Instead I'm going to suggest to dedicate a physics layer for things you want to be able to pick up like this.

You can specify to your `PhysicsRayQueryParameters3D` what layers it should detect by setting its `collision_mask`, so it only picks objects that have the layer you want.

So you can have a second physics body (an `StaticBody3D` would do) which is in that dedicated layer and has a collider that matches the `Sprite3D` much closer.

That is, you can keep your current physics object with its collider which would have layer and mask that interact with the game world (this one could have a wide base, for example), and a second physics object that only has a layer that allows you to pick it up but won't interact with anything in the game world (so it can be thin and tall to better match the `Sprite3D`).

*You could rotate this second physics body to `look_at` the `get_viewport().get_camera_3d()` if you need to mimic billboarding. And you can also update its collision shape in runtime if needed.*

---

*By the way, your physic objects have a property `input_ray_pickable` which enables `_input_event`, if that works for you, it might save you some coding (you might not need `intersect_ray`). If it doesn't, having it enabled is a waste, so consider turning it off.*